# magic combination

Tags: unix, kill

I stopped using the Unix process ctr + z. Then I tried to kill the process and did not work. A friend from school was recommended to use the kill -9 process_id. What is the magic combination?

Comment: should go on superuser.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/107543/bash-man-page-kill-pid-vs-kill-9-pid

Comment: Never trust "friend from school" recommendations, `kill -9 process_id` is quite a poor practice.

Comment: @jlliagre so what would you suggest as the correct practice?

Comment: "-9" or more precisely SIGKILL is a last resort signal, not something to routinely use. The correct practice for a suspended process is to first resume it as already answered. Should you want to kill it then, start by sending the "-15" signal (a.k.a SIGTERM) which give a chance for the process to exit gracefully.

Answer (score 8):

Just follow normal kill by a resume (SIGCONT or in shell, `fg` the job).

The signal will only be received after the process is resumed (it cannot receive the signal because... you suspended it :))

So,

```
kill -CONT $pid
```

to resume it if you no longer have access to the terminal or shell controlling the job