# Stopping command from terminal without stopping shell script that started that command

Tags: shell, script

I have a script like this:

> #!/var/bin/bash
>
> tail -f /path/to/file.txt
>
> tail -f /path/to/other/file
>
> ...
>    `

How can I stop tail -f without stopping whole script?

Any idea?

Comment: Are you really asking "How do I stop a process in Unix?" http://superuser.com/questions/107543/bash-man-page-kill-pid-vs-kill-9-pid

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_04_03.html -- 4.3.5.7. Interrupting your processes

Comment: This question is easily solved by research

Answer (score 0):

In another shell you can write

```
 pgrep -lf tail
```

the output should be similar to this:

> > 9845 tail -f /path/to/file.txt

**PID** of the process in this case is 9845 
You can stop (kill) it with

```
kill 9845
```

if it doesn't function you can use kill **-9** 9845.

Note: if you kill the process of 1st "tail -f" line of the script, 
the script will proceed till the second "tail -f" (tail -f /path/to/other/file) and stops again there.